# Alias tag [open-tracing] to [opentracing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[open-tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-tracing) should be [opentracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opentracing).

[The official name](http://opentracing.io/) does not have a space in it. It won't let me create the correct version.

Comment: Workaround: Remove from the 2 questions that have it, wait until midnight, then add corrected version.

Answer (score 1):

The check for creating nearly same tags is not there for ♦ moderators.
<sub>*marks it down as a perk to make fun of non mods*</sub>

I have manually retagged both the posts from [open-tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-tracing) to the new [opentracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opentracing). Do add a tag wiki when you are free!